# how to display 2 lists filtered by another field from one model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Model: Article.
id.
name.
type: ['code', 'design']

API gets all articles

How can I display two lists:
all articles with type ='Code',
all articles with type = 'Design'

In other words, is it possible to filter the API query
Or is it better to do it on the API side?

Extra: same as above but in a nested environment (ie Articles belong to Category. How to do it on the category detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed properties.  I built a sample component:

**EDIT:** Took some time to DRY it up.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article-list title="Code Articles" :articles="codeArticles" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article-list title="Design Articles" :articles="designArticles" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ArticleList from './ArticleList.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      ArticleList
    },
    data() {
      return {
        articles: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Article1',
            type: 'Code'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Article2',
            type: 'Design'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Article3',
            type: 'Code'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Article4',
            type: 'Design'
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      codeArticles() {
        return this.articles.filter(article => article.type === 'Code');
      },
      designArticles() {
        return this.articles.filter(article => article.type === 'Design');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

ArticleList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="two-filtered-lists">
    <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>TYPE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">
          <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ article.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ article.type }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      articles: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: related question with belongs_to relationship for Tasklist
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66806244/3063798